# Build expression tree using Expression.<Factory method> syntax dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, tree, expression

I have the following code that builds an IQueryable

```
Expression<Func<TParentEntity, TChildEntity, bool>> joinExpr =
    ctx.GetJoinExpression<TParentEntity, TChildEntity>();

Expression<Func<TChildEntity, bool>> childSelectionExpression =
    GetExpression<TChildEntity>(ctx);

return
    from parentEntity in ctx.GetQueryable<TParentEntity>()
        .AsExpandable()
    let childEntities = 
        from child in ctx.GetQueryable<TChildEntity>()
        where joinExpr.Invoke(parentEntity, child)
        select child
    where childEntities.Any(childSelectionExpression)
    select parentEntity;
```

I've been trying (unsuccesfully) build the expression tree that would return the same result.
I would like to have an expression `Expression<Func<TParentEntity,bool> parentExpression` 
that i could use as following:

```
from parentEntity in ctx.GetQueryable<TParentEntity>()
    .AsExpandable()
where parentExpression.Invoke(parentEntity)
select parentEntity
```

Does anybody think this is possible? I believe so, but i am unable to solve it...

Comment: What does `GetJoinExpression` do? What O/RM are we talking about?

Comment: see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx may be helpfull.

Comment: GetJoinExpression builds an expression that expresses the relation between the parent and child.
It is implemented using reflection - it searches for the AssociationAttribute, which supplies the property names i use in the expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureaka :-)

The method at the end of this post returns an expression of type `Expression<Func<TParentEntity,bool>>`, let's call that one the parentExpression.

When used like this:

---

`var data = (from parentEntity in parentEntities.AsExpandable()
 where parentExpression.Invoke(parentEntity) select parentEntiy).ToList()`

---

What happens is actually something like this:

---

`var data = (from parentEntity in parentEntities.AsExpandable() 
let childeren = childEntities.Where(c => c.parentId = parentEntity.Id)
where childeren.Any([childSelectionLambda]) 
select parent).ToList()`

---

By being able to express the child criteria in one Lambda of type
`Expression<Func<TParentEntity, bool>>`
it is easy to combine multiple child criteria (which are expressed as parent criteria) or other (normal) parent criteria using PredicateBuilder.And().

Tests are green for EF and linq to SQL (and sql ce) :-)

```
override public Expression<Func<TParentEntity, bool>> 
        GetParentExpression<TParentEntity>( IDynamicQueryAdapter ctx ) 
    {

        // Define parameters needed in expresion tree
        ParameterExpression parentParameter = 
            Expression.Parameter (typeof (TParentEntity), "parent");
        ParameterExpression childParameter = 
            Expression.Parameter (typeof (TChildEntity), "child");

        // Define the IQueryable<TChildEntity> as 
        // a constant for use in the expression tree.
        IQueryable<TChildEntity> childDatasource = 
            ctx.GetQueryable<TChildEntity>().AsExpandable();
        ConstantExpression childDatasourceConstant = 
            Expression.Constant (childDatasource);

        // Get MethodInfo instance, needed for the MethodCallExpression
        MethodInfo anyMethodInfoChildEntity = 
            QueryHelper.GetQueryableAnyMethod<TChildEntity> ();

        // Get the lambda expression
        // required to select only those child entities
        // which meet the user defined criteria
        Expression<Func<TChildEntity, bool>> childSelectionExpression = 
            GetExpression<TChildEntity> (ctx);

        // Use the ExpressionParameter childParamter for the
        // ChildSelectionExpression and strip Expression.Invoke using Expand()
        Expression<Func<TChildEntity, bool>> lambda5 =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<TChildEntity, bool>> (
            Expression.Invoke (childSelectionExpression, childParameter),
                    childParameter).Expand ();


        #region Express the parent child relation
        PropertyInfo parentKeyPropertyInfo = null;
        PropertyInfo childKeyPropertyInfo = null;
        ctx.GetParentChildAssociationProperties (
            typeof (TParentEntity), typeof (TChildEntity),
            out parentKeyPropertyInfo, out childKeyPropertyInfo);
        Expression parentPropertyExpression =
            Expression.Property (parentParameter, parentKeyPropertyInfo.Name);
        Expression childPropertyExpression =
            Expression.Property (childParameter, childKeyPropertyInfo.Name);

        if( childKeyPropertyInfo.PropertyType != parentKeyPropertyInfo.PropertyType )
        {
            // TODO: what if the property types are incomparable >> exception.
            // some more code is needed!!
            Type nullableParentType = 
                typeof (Nullable<>)
                .MakeGenericType (parentKeyPropertyInfo.PropertyType);

            if( childKeyPropertyInfo.PropertyType == nullableParentType )
            {
                childPropertyExpression =
                    Expression.Convert (childPropertyExpression,
                        parentKeyPropertyInfo.PropertyType);
            }
            else if( childKeyPropertyInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType )
            {
                Type nullableChildType =
                    typeof (Nullable<>).MakeGenericType (childKeyPropertyInfo.PropertyType);
                if( parentKeyPropertyInfo.PropertyType == nullableChildType )
                {
                    parentPropertyExpression =
                        Expression.Convert (parentPropertyExpression,
                        childKeyPropertyInfo.PropertyType);
                }
            }
        } 
        #endregion
        var lambda4 = Expression.Lambda<Func<TChildEntity, bool>> (
            Expression.Equal (
                parentPropertyExpression, 
                childPropertyExpression), childParameter );

        var predicate = lambda4.And(lambda5).Expand();

        Expression<Func<TParentEntity, bool>> parentSelectionExpression = 
            Expression.Lambda<Func<TParentEntity,bool>>(
            Expression.Call (
                null, 
                anyMethodInfoChildEntity, 
                new Expression[] { childDatasourceConstant, predicate }),
            new[]{parentParameter});

        return parentSelectionExpression;
    }
```

note: PredicateBuilder, extension AsExpandable(), extenstion Expand() ... are part of LinqKit
For more info about those visit: [Linqkit into](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I know what you want and because I have tries it, I am sorry to inform you that you have arrived in a world of pain. Here is a partial workaround:

```
Expression<Func<TParentEntity, TChildEntity, bool>> joinExpr =
    ctx.GetJoinExpression<TParentEntity, TChildEntity>();

Expression<Func<TChildEntity, bool>> childSelectionExpression =
    GetExpression<TChildEntity>(ctx);

return
    (from parentEntity in ctx.GetQueryable<TParentEntity>()
        .AsExpandable()
    let childEntities = 
        from child in ctx.GetQueryable<TChildEntity>()
        where joinExpr.Invoke(parentEntity, child)
        select child
    select parentEntity).Where(childSelectionExpression);
```

You have to transform all query calls that use expression variable like I did it. Not always possible but I think in your case it is.

Comment: A world of pain indeed :-) but worth it!